# Calculo em javascript sem dar refresh na página

Tags: javascript, html

Estou tentando criar um script em `javascript` para pegar um valor inserido pelo usuário, e multiplicar pelo valor especificado, mas sempre que eu clico no botão, ele efetua os cálculos, mas, ele atualiza a pagina em seguida, zerando.

Segue código que usei:

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  var valorProduto = "";
  valorProduto = document.getElementById("vp").value * 2;
  document.getElementById("valorST").innerHTML = valorProduto;
}
```

```html
<p>Valor do produto:
  <input type="text" id="vp">
</p>
<p id="valorST">valor</p>
<button id="btn">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Coloca um `return false;` depois da última linha do script.

Comment: possivelmente seu `button` pode estar dentro de um `form`, dependendo de como tiver implementado isso poderá dar um `refresh` na página se o `action` estiver vazio, se o `action` estiver preenchido, ele fará o redirecionamento, o `return false;` como dito pelo @zooboomafoo pode prevenir isso :)

Comment: Só mais uma coisa, isso não tem nada haver com loop rs

Comment: Entendi Marcelo, realmente me expressei errado no começo, rs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloca um `return false;` na última linha do script, assim ele para a execução do script. Talvez tenha um `<form>` aí e ele entenda o botão como `submit`.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
  var valorProduto = "";
  valorProduto = document.getElementById("vp").value * 2;
  document.getElementById("valorST").innerHTML = valorProduto;
  return false;
}
```

```html
<p>Valor do produto:
  <input type="text" id="vp">
</p>
<p id="valorST">valor</p>
<button id="btn">Calcular</button>
```

Comment: Yay! Funcionou! Retirei o botão do form e adicionei o codigo a ultima linha do js! Obrigado :D

Comment: Se te ajudou só colocar a resposta como correta. =D Que fica abaixo das setas de votação.